# Updating a list of a few dozen document resources in MongoEngine

Tags: python, performance, comparative-review, mongodb

This is my model:

```
class Subject(Document):
    uri = StringField(required=True,unique=True)
    resources = EmbeddedDocumentListField('Resource')
    date_modified = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    meta = {
        'indexes': [
            {'fields': ['uri'], 'unique': True},
        ],
    }

class Resource(EmbeddedDocument):
    uri = StringField(required=True)
    title = StringField()
    snippet = StringField()
    image = StringField()
    source = StringField()
    adapter = StringField()
```

I am not sure if I am following the 'ideal' process when updating the embedded document. Based on Subject modified date, I need to re-set the resources. Old resources need to be deleted, as we only want current ones.

Approach 1: Add all resources to list, then save

```
resources = []
for p in programmes:
    #create or update the resource of this document with provided programme
    resources.append(Resource(uri=p['uri'], title=p['title'],snippet = p['snippet'],image = p['image'],adapter = p['adapter'],source = p['source']))
subject.resources = resources
subject.date_modified = datetime.datetime.now()
subject.save()
```

Approach 2: Using update, set each one separately.

```
    subject.update(unset__resources=None)
    for p in programmes:
        #create or update the resource of this document with provided programme
        resource = Resource(uri=p['uri'], title=p['title'],snippet = p['snippet'],image = p['image'],adapter = p['adapter'],source = p['source'])
        subject.update(add_to_set__resources = resource )
        subject.update(set__date_modified=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Which approach is better/more efficient? I expect to get up to 50 resources, no more than that.

Comment: Do a bulk-save. It's vastly more performant, which will help when you inevitably start getting 5k records instead of 50.